# AWS lambda for running long scripts and use of databse

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-batch

We need to run a python script which will also need of a database connection.

The script will run atleast 1 hour. currently We are checking on the AWS lambda but that allows max 15 minutes of script execution.
So please let us know how we can use all this so that we can run the long sripts

Comment: If you don't need to process the results of the DB operation, you could start the DB operation (e.g. call a stored procedure) and exit the lambda. In mysql, I *think* the operation will keep running even if the connection is terminated. Pros: can use lamdba, only pay for time to initiate the operation. Cons: No feedback, can't know if there were any errors, can't process query results.

Comment: In general, I'd agree with the other answers and recommend Fargate, Batch, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I dont think AWS lambda suites your needs, I would suggest using
https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, you can't do it, unless you want to do it chunks, e.g. using multiple executions of single lambda in a loop or several consecutive lambdas. Such lambdas could be synchronized using [step functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/).

Lambda 15 minutes limit is a **hard limit**, which [can't be extended](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html) even if you contact AWS support.

> The following limits apply to function configuration, deployments, and execution. **They cannot be changed**.

I would recommend looking at other solutions, e.g. [ECS Fargate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/AWS_Fargate.html). It is serverless and allows running arbitrary long tasks in the form of Docker containers.

Answer (score 2):

Lambda by itself is not the tool for the job, with its cutoff [limit of 15 minutes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html) you're looking at having to use either Lambda with another tool, or another tool entirely.

If you want to use Lambda to perform the long running script I would suggest looking at [step functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/) as an orchestrator or Lambdas. My tips for this are the following:

- Break down specific parts of the script in logical functions, these will deploy as your Lambdas. Either use the functionality of [input/output filtering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-input-output-filtering.html) or store large data sets either on [S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) or [EFS](https://aws.amazon.com/efs/) (an E[FS mount can be shared between Lambdas](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-efs-for-aws-lambda-in-your-serverless-applications/) now).
- Parallelise using multiple Lambda functions to improve speed wherever you can.
- Use logical flows such as retries and delays in case of issues.

If you're not too strict on Lambda here are a few other suggestions:

- [Fargate](https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/) - Use this option if you want the benefits of serverless without the constraints of Lambda. Convert your script into a Containerised application and schedule it using CloudWatch Events.
- [EMR](https://aws.amazon.com/emr/) - AWS managed Hadoop service, use the benefits of MPP (Massively Parallel Processing) to perform tasks across a number of nodes, this could lead to significant speed increase in the script where parallelisation is possible.
- [EC2 Batch](https://aws.amazon.com/batch/) - The traditional EC2 batch job, again you would be parallelising the functionality.

All of these also can be used with step functions.

There is a tutorial by AWS to [Create a Serverless Workflow](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/create-a-serverless-workflow-step-functions-lambda/) that will help you to learn what you need to do.